# ptrace SIGTRAP not handled

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

For `test1.c`, I get:

```
5
133
1
0
```

It means that the child process firstly get `SIGTRAP` (5), cause by `execl`.
The last three lines indicate that the child process dies due to the `SIGSTRAP`
signal from the parent.

```
// test1.c
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int main() {
  pid_t child;
  int status = 0;
  child = fork();
  if(child == 0) {
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
  } else {
    wait(&status);
    printf("%d\n", status >> 8);
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child, NULL, SIGTRAP);

    wait(&status);
    printf("%d\n", status);
    printf("%d\n", WIFSIGNALED(status));
    printf("%d\n", WIFEXITED(status));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

For `test2.c`, I get:

```
19
1029
0
0
1
```

19 is `SIGSTOP`, and `1029` is `(SIGTRAP | (PTRACE_EVENT_EXEC<<8))`, but the
last threes lines are beyond me. Why does the child process exit normally? What happend to the `SIGTRAP` signal from the parent?

```
// test2.c
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
int main() {
  pid_t child;
  int status = 0;
  child = fork();
  if(child == 0) {
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);
    raise(SIGSTOP);
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
  } else {
    wait(&status);
    ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, child, 0, PTRACE_O_TRACEEXEC);
    printf("%d\n", status >> 8);
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child, NULL, 0);

    wait(&status);
    printf("%d\n", status >> 8);
    ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child, NULL, SIGTRAP);

    wait(&status);
    printf("%d\n", status);
    printf("%d\n", WIFSIGNALED(status));
    printf("%d\n", WIFEXITED(status));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When dispatching a SIGNAL by the tracer with

```
ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, child, NULL, SIGXXXX);
```

The tracer is not notified for that signal - which makes sense. Otherwise, how else would you dispach a signal to a the tracee? You will always catch it.

> PTRACE_CONT
>                 Restart the stopped tracee process.  If data is nonzero, it is
>                 interpreted as the number of a signal to be delivered to the
>                 tracee; otherwise, no signal is delivered.  **Thus, for example,
>                 the tracer can control whether a signal sent to the tracee is
>                 delivered or not**.

If you want to stop the child from the parent you should use

```
kill(child_pid, SIGTRAP)
```

So, I guess that when you send the SIGTRAP in the first example - you simply send an unhandled signal to the process which will probably kill him.

I the other hand - PTRACE_TRACEME doesn't cause the the child to stop, so, it might as well already finished its exection when the SIGTRAP is dispatched.